# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each(data.results, function(i,data)

    var div_data = '<li class="right-block-list-image">'+ data.Model_Number +'</ul>';

});
```

Where is my syntax error within `div_data`?

Comment: You are missing a `{` after `function(i, data)`.

Answer (score 6):

Missing the open `{` after `function()`

```
$.each(data.results, function(i,data) {
// ----------------------------------^^  
    var div_data = '<li class="right-block-list-image">'+ data.Model_Number +'</ul>';

});
```

Unlike the braces in `if, while, for` blocks, `function` braces are not optional if there's only one subsequent statement inside. You had the closing `}`, so I suspect you know that.